# Как отображать какой либо pane при нажатии кнопки?JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Я недавно начал работать с этой библиотекой. И мне нужно выполнить определённую задачу, а реализации данной в интернете я не нашёл. У меня есть 3 кнопки и мне нужно чтобы после нажатии которых либо контент Pane менялся либо сам Pane. Кто знает вариант как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно присвоить id вашему pane в контроллере

```
 @FXML
 Pane pane;
```

и по нажатии кнопки его очищать. У кнопки должно быть прописан метод onAction().Пусть он будет называться crButton1

```
public void crButton1(){
    pane.getChildren().clear();
    //Затем присвоить ему новый Pane и содержимое
    pane.getChildren().add(createNewPain());
}
```

пропишите содержимое которое хотите вставить

```
 public Pane createNewPain(){
        return new Pane();
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую. Отпишу получилось ли у меня